# Usability disadvantages to an Opera-style menu as the standard navigation model for web sites?

Tags: usability, navigation, menu

**Premises:**

(1) Opera-style menu refers to a navigation menu which shows or hides when you click anywhere on the left edge of the application window. It must have been introduced by the original Opera browser. It exists to this day by means of various add-ons for Mozilla and I think it is native to the Vivaldi browser;

(2) It has become quite popular to keep a web site's navigation on the same show/hide principle by means of the hamburger button. The difference is that the click area is a single button, usually on the top right and the navigation pane may take either the whole screen or the top section;

(3) Considering my personal satisfaction with the Opera style menu (happily using it to this day as a Mozilla add-on) and considering how cognitively challenging modern web sites are, with all their distractions, heavy visuals and navigation areas competing with the page-specific content, I came up with the notion that it might be just right to move all navigation elements (everything which we'd otherwise place in header, footer and side menu) to a scrollable, Opera-style navigation pane;

(4) The advantages I can see:

- each page is free of distractions from its page-specific content;
- superior to hamburger menu button by virtually taking no screen
  estate, while providing much larger clicking area (no need to strain
  your wrist muscles to target a single button on screen); when it
  comes to mobile devices, we already have seen it by the left to right
  swipe;
- makes deep level navigation achievable - let's say you have a real estate portal, with tons of navigation categories and search filters - you can keep the major categories in that menu, while placing the complex search filter panes in the page content area
- suitable for standardizing web site experiences: no matter the web site language, topic or complexity, users can expect all their navigation options in that place. Currently the only consistent navigation elements across all sorts of web sites are only the footer and the logo;
- equally suitable for small navigation elements volume (e.g. only breadcrumb, search field and a small number of categories) and big one (given that the menu'd be scrollable, you can have plenty of stuff there, e.g. think of e-commerce platforms with numerous product categories);

(5) for the sake of this question, let's assume that this type of navigation has become widespread enough and users know where to expect it on screen;

(6) one issue I can spot is that such menu would interfere with the browser's own Opera-style menu, as is the case on my browser. For the sake of this question, let's dismiss this for a while;

**Question:**

Could you point specific usability issues with this type of navigation approach?

Please, provide concrete examples when and why that won't work or tell which usability laws are being violated.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you see any particular usability issues with this type of navigation, so are you asking the question because there is some potential issue you want to address or are you just curious? Perhaps if you pointed out some issues you do have it will be easier to provide a response as to whether there are ways to alleviate it for the user.

Comment: @ Michael Lai - I think this type of navigation is superior to anything else tried so far and it should become standard. I want to check if I may be wrong about that.